# Codeigniter Error : Undefined Offset 1

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having problem with my code. I am getting error as below.

> error in this code $vf=$bn[1];
>
> $this->_data['kabupaten'] -> post in html
>
> This error :
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined offset:
> 1
>
> Filename: mustahik/mustahik_controller.php
>
> Line
> Number: 1108

My controller code is as below

```
$this->_data['kabupaten'] = "";
if($this->_data['kab'] != $this->_data['kabupaten']) {
    $vf = $this->_data['kab'] ;
    $cf = $vf;
    echo "kk".$cf;
} else {
    $bn = explode('.',($this->_data['kabupaten']), 3);
    $vf = $bn[1]; /// error here
    $cf = $vf;
    echo "kk".$cf;
}
```

My view is a below

```
<tr>
    <td>Kab/Kota<span class="red">*</span></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="kab" value="<?php echo $survey['kabupaten'];?>">
        <select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten" style="width: 100%;" class="select2" onchange="get_districts(this.value);" >
        </select>
        <option value="<?php echo $survey['kabupaten'];?>"></option>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Anyone having idea what the problem is?

Comment: check first if it has indeed index 1

Comment: what's the data in `$this->_data['kabupaten']` at the time the error occurs? from what it appears `$this->_data['kabupaten']` contains no `.` so `explode` only returns an array with one element which is the original string

Comment: hold up. you set `$this->_data['kabupaten']` to be an empty string `$this->_data['kabupaten'] = "";`. that means when it goes to your if statement it will always be an empty string so your doing `$this->_data['kab'] != ""` and `$bn=explode('.',"", 3);`

Comment: sorry guys ,, i edit the question .. i'm adding description html .

Comment: @tara you edit doesn't change anything and my comment still stands. `$this->_data['kabupaten']` before it gets to the if statement is set to be an empty string as such you are doing an explode on a string which has no dots in so it'll always return an array with only 1 element which is an empty string. the third argument of `explode` doesn't guarantee you `array(3)`. see [this example](http://www.tehplayground.com/#9d1Hl0jGY), notice how only the third var_dump returns an `array(3)`.

Comment: anyway thanks for discussion .. i find the solve .. list ($an, $bn)= array_pad(explode('.', $this->_data['kabupaten'], 2), 2, null);

Answer (score 0):

Place  ending tag after  will solve the problem:

```
           <tr>
                <td>Kab/Kota<span class="red">*</span></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="kab" value="<?php echo $survey['kabupaten'];?>">
                  <select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten" style="width: 100%;" class="select2" onchange="get_districts(this.value);" >

                    <option value="<?php echo $survey['kabupaten'];?>"></option>
                  </select>
                </td>
          </tr>
```